# Different actions on multiple Keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so my question (im hoping) is fairly simple. I want to know what to do so that I can create different events for the same keycode. For instance Id like to fade out a div and fade a new one in on the first keypress, then fade that one out and fade a new one in on keypress.

Thanks!

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
  if (event.keyCode == '40') {

    $('.div-1').fadeOut("slow")
    $('.div-2').fadeIn("slow")

   // I'd like this event to occur on the Second keydown

    $('.div-2').fadeOut("slow")
    $('.div-3').fadeIn("slow")
   }  
});
```

Comment: try not to forget semicolons... it will help you... promise...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var hits = 0;

$(document).keydown(function() {
  if (event.keyCode == '40') {
    hits++;
    if (hits % 2 == 0) {
       // I'd like this event to occur on the Second keydown
       $('.div-2').fadeOut("slow");
       $('.div-3').fadeIn("slow");

    } else {

      $('.div-1').fadeOut("slow");
      $('.div-2').fadeIn("slow");
   }  
});
```

Comment: hmm, that didnt seem to work. What if I had many divs. Im trying to create a slideshow using this method that is accessible mainly by using the keyboard arrows (so you understand the context)

Should it just be multiple if statements?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can see is create local variable. In your case (slodeshow) you need to count each keydown and parse div class.

```
    var hits = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function() {
      if (event.keyCode == '40') {          
          $('.div-' + hits).fadeOut("slow")
          $('.div-' + (hits + 1)).fadeIn("slow")         
          hits++;
       }  
    });
```